# Event Bridge Rule selection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I was trying to create a rule for AWS EventBridge for one of my requirements. I have added few rules and depends on the rule I am selecting a specific AWS resource as my Target. Whenever any of the filter condition is getting satisfied the respective AWS resource is getting triggered. But I want a scenario like whenever none of the filter condition is getting satisfied then I need to trigger an AWS resource. So, similar to a conditional statement in a programming language by default how else will be triggered if none of the conditions is getting satisfied. Is there any possible solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current solution for this problem. I recommend you use the feedback functionality within the AWS console to pass on your request to AWS.